# weird stack overflow in Quicksort

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, quicksort

I've written an implementation of Quicksort algorithm with vectors and it works fine with a pivot in the middle but to my astonishment when I change the pivot selection part to be done randomly the program gives a stack overflow error! This is while it's said that the pivot that is selected has no effect on the algorithm and it makes sense to me too, but I don't know what's causing this issue in my code:

```
void quickSort(int low, int high, vector<int>& arr) {
int i = low, j = high;

//If I choose the pivot from the middle, works fine:
int pivot = arr[(low + high) / 2];

//But the next three lines won't work (instead of the line above):
//srand(time(0));
//int pivotIndex = rand() % arr.size();
//int pivot = arr.at(pivotIndex);

while (i <= j) {
    while (arr.at(i) < pivot) { ++i; }
    while (arr.at(j) > pivot) { --j; }
    if (i <= j) {
        swapElem(arr, i, j);
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
}
if (low < j)
    quickSort(low, j, arr);
if (i < high)
    quickSort(i, high, arr);
return;
}
```

I'm using VS15 and also debugged my program to find an infinite recursion or another problem (took me years though :) b/c there are a lot of recursions) and it ended successfully! without giving the same error! But if I run the whole program together, it gives the stack overflow error! Somewhere else here on SO I read that it has something to do with "debug" and "release" profiles so I switched my build configuration to release but it didn't work too.

Please help and if you need the whole code I will put it. TYIA.

Comment: We don't need the "whole" code. We need the exact amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem with one single copy & paste operation, but not a line more.

Comment: You need to add checks that this `quickSort` is not recursive on all paths. Or add recursion depth check.

Comment: @VTT Shall you explain more or give me a link so I can read about it? Is recursion depth check a rising counter inside a loop?

Comment: Counter should be incremented each time you enter this function. So you can check then it is not getting too high. And check whether those intervals are valid. Actually it would be better to get rid of recursion completely.

Comment: I wonder how I can get rid of recursions if I want quick sort? Using better alternatives?!

Comment: I don't believe recursion depth check or getting rid of recursions will help, since your function works without the random pivot choosing, which suggests that the problem is in the random pivot choosing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you are modding by `arr.size()` instead of `high - low`? Example: if you choose an index higher than `high`, then the partition will do nothing and you will recursively call again without decreasing the size. If this happens often enough, which it probably will, especially for lower sizes, then the stack will overflow.

To fix replace that line with:

```
int pivotIndex = rand() % (high - low + 1) + low;
```

Comment: Since both `low` and `high` are apparently intended to be valid array indices, the proper expression for pivot index would be `rand() % (high - low + 1) + low`